# symfony2 advanced select in form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

Is there a way to add from client side either collection or drop down based on what user is selected in drop down in main form ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I use jQuery to get part of the collection (extra input fields). In controller I have form builder that creates and returns those inputs as HTML. You can add condition and pass parameters (I use POST and GET is only for testing) and get different collection.

```
/**    
* @Route("/gcco/{id}", name="name", options={"expose"=true})
* @Method({"GET", "POST"})
*/
public function functionName($id){
     $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type here');
     $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData, array('csrf_protection' => false));
     $form->add('name', 'type', array(
                    'label' => 'label',
                    'label_attr' => array(
                         'title' => 'title',
                    ),
                    'required' => false,
               ));
          }
     }
     $form = $form->getForm();

     $html = $this->renderView('YourBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

     return new JsonResponse(
          array(
            'html' => $html
          )
     );
}
```

And in form.html.twig file add so you will get only input fields:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

In JsonResponse you will get your collection.

Maybe it's not the best way but it works for me every time.

Other way is to pass JSON back to JavaScript and build all inputs there.

Comment: Thank You ! This worked, I'm getting form-part exactly where I need it. Only thing is that it is not sent in main form array through request, I have to process it manually in controller.

Comment: Just add new values to the same POSt array. E.g. if your main POST array name is mainPostArray (<input id="mainPostArray_value" id="mainPostArray[value]">). I add new values this way and in controller have only one array. Hope it helps.